# I'd like to make a Linq to object (Basic, Dictionary)

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to find a elegant way(s) to make a data structure using Linq.

(From text file to Dictionary/List).

I do not know how to start it.

myFile.text is like this (tab seperated)

```
Apple   Fruit   2016-March-24-01
Rice    Grain   2016-March-24-02
Milk    Dairy   2016-March-24-03
Egg     Poultry 2016-March-24-04
...
..
.
```

my codes (sorry for the elementary works)

```
string myFile = @"...\myFile.txt";
string myContent = File.ReadAllText(myFile);  
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach( string x in Regex.Split(myContent, @"\r\n") )
{
    if( x != "" )
    {
        string[] myArray = Regex.Split(x, @"\t");
        myDictionary.Add(myArray[0], myArray[1]);  // I need the first two items only.
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(myDictionary.Count.ToString() + "\n\n" + string.Join("\n", myDictionary.Keys) + "\n\n" + string.Join("\n", myDictionary.Values));
```

Help please.

Comment: The first record: 2016-March-24-01, what does `01` mean here? Number of  tables?

Comment: @DannyChen  that is just numbers (meaningless). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the following.

```
var myDictionary = File.ReadLines(myFile)
                       .Where(x => x != string.Empty)
                       .Select(x => x.Split('\t'))
                       .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Ahhhhhhh. Easy (because of your nice porting).

Comment: How about "Speed"? I'd like to find the fastest way. "ReadLines" is fast enough ?

Comment: @Jason You could try `File.ReadAllLines` and test to see which is faster.  The size of the file would likely be factor, but I doubt there would be much difference.  The real benefit of `File.ReadLines` is that it reads the file one line at a time instead of reading the entire file into memory (useful if the file is large).

Comment: @juharr Thanks for your comment. The total lines should be around 40,000 and the contents/complexity is just like above mentioned (I guess, it is short and simple).

Comment: But, I have to read it repeatedly, let's say every 2 seconds and, of course, some lines are added and removed.

Comment: LINQ looks great. It is beautiful. Really ^^